Is there a way to look at apps running in the background, with a view to closing them
I am talking about services.  But some apps run in the background even when you "Close All".
Some examples

Parallel Space
Email / Message Apps
Apps with widgets installed

I am using Samsung Note 20 with Android 13.  Its not rooted and I can't enable developer mode (as some security conscious apps will not run and I need to use them).
Is there a way to look at these and possibly close selected ones?
Asked why I wanted to do this - two reasons

For privacy, for example Parallel space is still running after I have finished using it.
I have almost 400 apps, and the phone gets sluggish unless I can manage them.  The included software (Android or Samsung) does a reasonable job putting apps to deep sleep etc.,  but it doesn't get all of them.


What version of Android, and what device?

Is it closing them to prevent battery consumption ? If that is the case install PMX developed by Irfan and deny/ignore all apps having RUN_IN-BACKGROUND & RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND permissions. That would stop those apps generating any wakelocks to keep the device alive or run at all. If your device is not rooted, you can grant PMX elevated privileges by wireless debugging (see app help)

Thanks @beeshyams. Also you can view and force stop running apps using my app WhatsRunning. See details in How to view background apps running on Android? and How to view background services running on Android? and How to stop background apps on Android?.

@IrfanLatif, I had a look at Whatsrunning and it requires ADB or root.  I am not rooted and I can't have developers option enabled, otherwise some of my banking an government security apps wont run.  I had forgotten about that and purchased PMX anyway.  :-)  They look good, I will install them on my spare phone later and have a play.

I was hoping for something simple and discovered the following.
When I close all running apps, I see this screen.  At the top of the screen (not very prominently), it shows you the number of apps running in the background.

If I press on that line, I see what I was after

And I can stop selected ones here.
